# Não consigo obter retorno de 'floats' atraves de expressões

Tags: python, float

Quando tento dar `print(6/10)` obtenho um `int` (0) ao invés de um `float` (0.6)

E se eu der `type(6/10)` retorna `int`.

Estou seguindo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5hnMWGxRvw&list=PLesCEcYj003QxPQ4vTXkt22-E11aQvoVj&index=16) e fazendo exatamente os mesmos passos tanto no pyCharm quanto no IDLE, no entanto ele consegue obter resultados 'float' e eu não.

[image: SS]

Comment: Não faço ideia, comigo deu certo http://ideone.com/WN9h4h acho difícil dar errado.

Comment: @bigown uso Linux. Será que tem algo a ver?

Comment: O ideone também usa. E não poderia fazer diferença dependendo do SO.

Comment: Enquanto isto você pode ajudar a ganete a criar o novo site para assuntos de TI que não são de programação. Faça o commit (não esquece de confirmar o e-mail). Se tiver o número mínimo de interessados, o site será criado. E se conseguir indicar para outras pessoas também, seria mais legal ainda. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues?referrer=iQLJgvwKWiaSZMVw5WkVIw2 Se desejar saber mais detalhes, veja: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2482/101 dê um up no comentário para eu saber que você leu e eu possa apagar.

Comment: @bigown vou mandar 1 print

Comment: @bigown atualizei a resposta com o print!

Comment: @bigown Que que isso?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando o Python 2.7. Não recomendo usá-lo, prefira usar a versão 3.0 em diante. Primeiro porque você está seguindo um tutorial usando esta versão, segundo porque não há ganhos em usar um versão mais antiga a não ser que você tenha código legado, o que não é o caso.

Realmente há esta diferença de comportamento. O Python 2.7 tinha esses "problemas" que obviamente foram consertados na versão mais recente para seguir a filosofia do Python e não usar a filosofia de outra linguagem como acontecia antes.

```
DeviaSerFloat = 6/10 #inteiro ou flutuante dependendo da implementação
EhFloat = 6.0/10.0 #força ponto flutuante
EhInt = 6//10 #força inteiro
print(DeviaSerFloat)
print(EhFloat)
print(EhInt)
```

Veja o [Python 2.7 executando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iVWVfK).

Agora veja o 3.0 [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SDMgRr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FloatDivision). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/FloatDivision.py).

Comment: Isso não é um "problema", simplesmente o design da linguagem até certo ponto seguia o do C (onde inteiro dividido por inteiro dava inteiro), e depois disso parou de seguir. A linha 2.X manteve o comportamento antigo, por compatibilidade, o que é sensato. Não há razão pra se evitar o 2.7, havendo um bom motivo para se usá-lo é claro (por exemplo, a última versão LTS do Ubuntu ainda usa o 2.X, o que significa que essa pode ser a versão padrão encontrada em diversos servidores).

Comment: É um problema para ele. Ele quer seguir um tutorial feito para o 3.0 mas usar o 2.7. Isto é um problema. Eu acho que só existe uma razão sensata para usar o 2.7, ter código legado que não é o caso dele. E se a versão antiga não tinha um problema com isto, porque consertaram? Ou voc~e acha que estragaram?

Comment: Bom, a tendência das linguagens modernas é usar o "princípio do menor assombro": faça a divisão "correta", e se você quer uma divisão que respeite o tipo use um operador diferente. Por isso não, não acho que estragaram, concordo que foi um avanço. Sobre usar o 2.7, até bem pouco tempo atrás eu usava por duas razões: 1) precisar de bibliotecas que só tinham pro 2.7 (acho que entra na sua categoria de código legado); 2) precisar dar suporte a ambientes que só tinham o 2.X (e poucas possibilidades pra instalar uma versão mais recente). Hoje em dia esses problemas estão bastante minimizados.

Answer (score 5):

Isso se deve a uma mudança na semântica da divisão entre as versões 2.X e 3.X do Python.

No Python 2.X operações entre inteiros sempre retornam um inteiro, de modo que `6/10` é interpretado como a divisão inteira - e portanto arredondado para zero. É necessário converter um dos operandos para float para fazer a divisão em ponto flutuante: `6.0/10` ou `6/10.0`. Esse comportamento foi "herdado" de linguagens tipo o C.

No Python 3.X a divisão entre inteiros pode retornar um ponto flutuante. Para fazer uma divisão inteira nessa versão é necessário usar um outro operador: `6//10`. Esse comportamento é mais comum em linguagens modernas, sobretudo as de tipagem dinâmica.

O operador de divisão inteira funciona também no Python 2.X - e ele retorna um inteiro inclusive quando seus operandos são floats: `6.0 // 10.0` vai dar zero. Já o operador de divisão comum (chamado de *"true division"*) mantém o comportamento padrão de sua versão, por compatibilidade, mas se você quiser usar a nova semântica no Python 2.X basta fazer o seguinte *import*:

```
from __future__ import division
```

A partir daí, a divisão vai funcionar como no 3.X (se isso precisa ser feito em cada arquivo fonte ou não, não tenho certeza, teria que testar ou consultar alguma referência).

<sup>[Fonte](https://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/node7.html)</sup>